# Arduino RF24 library Delay after write function causes no byte availability

Tags: arduino, delay, radio-transmission

It's about the RF24 library you can find here. http://maniacbug.github.io/RF24/index.html

I transmit data from one Arduino to another using NRF24L01 radios.
When I use the write-function on the transmitter arduino (joystick is an array) and after that I put in a delay higher then 10, the available function returns false.

Transmitter

```
radio.write( joystick, sizeof(joystick) );
delay(20);
```

Receiver

```
if(!available())
  print('No data'); // delay > 10 --> No data will be printed
```

Why is it working with a delay of 10 but not above? Has it something to do with timeouts which is mentioned in the docs of the library?: http://maniacbug.github.io/RF24/classRF24.html#a4cd4c198a47704db20b6b5cf0731cd58

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You may like to ask @ http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: :Thanks for advice: I copied the conversation to this place: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/8129/arduino-rf24-library-delay-after-write-function-causes-no-byte-availability